# How does this command with which to "refresh the syslog process" work?

Tags: syslog, pidfile

On [http://www.cs.newpaltz.edu/~easwaran/Resources/commands.html](http://www.cs.newpaltz.edu/%7Eeaswaran/Resources/commands.html) the following command is listed as being meant to "Refresh the syslog process":

```bsh
kill -1 `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid`
```

I have seen this command in real-life use on an embedded device but I cannot wrap my mind around why someone would use it and how it works.

I understand the single parts this is made up off, but e.g. why is the `cat` subshell killed using a `HUP` signal is not something which makes sense to me.

Comment: What parts do you know? Do you know the purpose of `kill`? Do you know the purpose of `kill -1`? Do you know the purpose of `cat`? Do you know the purpose of `/var/run/syslogd.pid`? Do you know the purpose of backticks? I'm trying to find out how detailed an answer needs to be.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

syslogd would appear to do two things for the convenience of system administrators:

(a) If it is running, it posts its own pid (process id) in a well-known file. When it exits, it will attempt to remove this file.

(b) When it receives SIGHUP, it takes that as a hint that it should re-examine its configuration, because something might have changed recently. This is something of a convention: e.g. Unix cron daemons needed to be sent SIGHUP after a contab file was edited, to ensure any changes became effective.

Comment: The SIGHUP is directed torwards the `cat` command though and not `syslogd`…

Comment: Not so. The cat command is enclosed in (old-school) back-ticks. This is a "process substitution" which shell runs first, and it emits the file contents, which is the pid number. This then gets substituted as the real arg to the kill process, like `kill -1 2345`.

Comment: Ah, of course! I am just not used to the backticks anymore that I forgot about how they work! Thanks.